# Profile Python CPU Usage By Thread

Tags: python

I've got a multi-threaded Python application, and I'm currently troubleshooting very high (90% or more) CPU usage.

I'm going to be trying out the profiler, but I wanted to see if there is a way I can get CPU usage per thread from within the application.  I understand that os.times() will get CPU usage overall - is there something I can run from within each thread to get each thread's usage?  It would be very helpful to determine which thread is eating CPU.

Comment: What operating systems do you plan to test on / support?

Comment: Primarily Windows, but we also support Linux.  The high CPU usage is occurring on Windows, but we have not tested it on Linux at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the profiler, I don't think Python has much built-in for monitoring individual thread CPU usage. Also, [this post](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/465831/) provides an example of a simple implementation of a thread profiler. It appears mainly geared towards Unix-based systems, but it's a start.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simply use yappi. (https://code.google.com/p/yappi/) It transparently uses GetThreadTimes() if CPU clock type is selected for profiling. It will show you CPU time of a running thread.

See here also for an example: https://code.google.com/p/yappi/wiki/YThreadStats_v082

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you could take a look at the Process Explorer ("procexp.exe" shipped with [Microsoft's Sysinternals Tools](http://www.sysinternals.com/)). There's a tab "Threads" in the properties of each process which lists all threads and their CPU time.

If that doesn't give you enough information, use Python's [profiling mechanisms](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html), which aren't too hard to use.